# Is there a way to add to an existing balance or amount in a database column without just replacing it when updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I am building a budgeting app of sorts. So I need to be able to make a deposit and a withdrawal. However the update method replaces the previous amount rather than adding to it. When I google this question I get active record migrations. Is there something similar to update_attributes that adds on to rather than replacing? Or is there a db column type that works this way? 
This is what I have right now.

```
    def deposit
     account = find_account(params[:id])
     new_balance = account.balance += params[:account][:balance].to_f
     account.assign_attributes(balance: new_balance)
     if account.save
      redirect_to accounts_path
     else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

Comment: `new_balance = account.balance + params[:account][:balance].to_f` then update the attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use += on a field/attribute, you don't need the assign_attributes

```
def deposit
   account = find_account(params[:id])
   account.balance += params[:account][:balance].to_f
   if account.save
     redirect_to accounts_path
   else
     redirect_to :back
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pull the existing value to your client code, do your magic adding and then update the record with the new value?